# Jetson Nano comes with OpenCV 4.1.1., do I need to downgrade to 3.2. for melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, libopencv, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got a Jetson Nano running Ubuntu 18.04 and it comes with OpenCV 4.1.1. pre installed. I've read ROS melodic is meant to work with OpenCV 3.2. and I'm getting some catkin make errors due to conflict between versions, for example:

```
usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2, needed by /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1
```

Should I downgrade my system OpenCV to 3.2.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347754/jetson-nano-comes-with-opencv-4.1.1.,-do-i-need-to-downgrade-to-3.2.-for-melodic?/) by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2020-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [floda](https://answers.ros.org/users/55958/floda/) on 2020-06-21**:
Do you mind sharing your recipe in recompiling cv_bridge? I am badly stuck. Thank you.

**Comment by [Akr2712](https://answers.ros.org/users/56740/akr2712/) on 2020-08-18**:
Hi, Please check the this [vision_opencv](https://github.com/mikejmills/vision_opencv) to fix the issues with cv_bridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same issue lately.
You can downgrade with `sudo apt -y --allow-downgrades install libopencv-dev=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1` and hold (avoid it being upgraded) with `sudo apt-mark hold libopencv-dev`.

If you have time, try to work on making your packages compatible with OpenCV 4 (e.g. by removing usage of the C API) since focal, and therefore noetic, drops support for OpenCV 3. To make everything work on melodic, your best bet right now is to downgrade and hold.

---

Originally posted by [kmfrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/54620/kmfrick/) with karma: 26 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-05-09**:
Thanks! Managed to find and install from source releases of certain packages that were compatible with OpenCV 4 but it has been a real pain to get it to work because had to rebuild CV Bridge and many others...I think downgrading is probably better as you say until more packages work with OpenCV 4.

Will the downgrade command you posted remove OpenCV 4 from the Nano?

**Comment by [kmfrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/54620/kmfrick/) on 2020-05-10**:
Yes, it should remove OpenCV 4 and install version 3.2.0.

**Comment by [floda](https://answers.ros.org/users/55958/floda/) on 2020-06-21**:
@jorgemia Do you mind posting your steps in recompiling cv_bridge? I got badly stuck there.

**Comment by [jorgemia](https://answers.ros.org/users/52277/jorgemia/) on 2020-06-22**:
@floda Hey I did it a while back but basically installed someone's fork from github where they had changed files to support opencv 4. You can find info here that might be useful: [Github Issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/272) and you could check some of the pull requests on github. Some of them might have been merged already so cv_bridge might already support OpenCV4. Also, the latest noetic release of cv-bridge supports OpenCv4, you might be able to install that.